# using a variable mysql not working as expected?

Tags: mysql

It doesn't like the `limit` line below. How would I use the variable `@row` in this case to limit the result set?

```
SELECT @row := 5;
SELECT * FROM MyTable
limit @row
```

Error:

> Unexpected '@row'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be **nonnegative integer constants** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

So,

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable  
limit 5
```

Comment: You can use `?` placeholders in prepared statements, or in stored routines you can use integer-typed routine parameters or local variables. But not user variables, which have no declared type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a prepared statement...

```
SET @row = 5;
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT ', @row);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```